# Trying to store search terms to MySQL database and display the 5 most recent queries

Tags: php, mysql, database, echo

I have little experience with mysql, I wouldn't be asking this question if I knew how to actually store the searches in the first place. I basically have a simple search bar that's not a "real search engine" it just redirects you to an already existing page under the name of what you searched using header('location: $term').

Anyway what I'm aiming to do is store the searches in a database and echo the most recent 5 on a different html page. If anybody could help I'd very much appreciate it, thanks!

Sorry if this wasn't explained very well, I'm kind of new to coding.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, as you tagged PHP I assume that you're using PHP for your website. This link give you a good insight and proper solution to what you want to do http://www.phpsuperblog.com/php/insert-values-into-mysql-database-with-html-form-and-php/

Comment: Thank you! That's helped a lot but my problem now is displaying the variables on another page and only the most recent 5. If you can't help it's no problem thanks for your help!

Comment: Here is another tutorial to loop over a MySQL table and display the results. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQzWken2AxA